# Cannot ssh into instance created in eucalyptus

Tags: ssh, eucalyptus, passphrase

I installed the eucalyptus faststart3.4.2 iso from here http://downloads.eucalyptus.com/software/faststart/ and then I installed cloud in a box. Then creating an instance m1.small I am trying to ssh into the instance created by its IP. The VM is running and I can ping it, when ssh -i euca-demo.private 10.5.20.224 is run most probably it enters VM but asks for passphrase which I dont know because the image was given after installation that I used to create the instance. The message is

Enter passphrase for key 'euca-demo.private':

How can I enter without knowing the passphase? How to know the passphase?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to login as ec2-user?

$ ssh -i euca-demo.private ec2-user@10.5.20.224

Comment: I could ssh into the instance via cloud-user@<IP-of-instance> but cannot get into as ec2-user@<IP-of-instance> it shows Permission denied ( Public Key )

Answer (score 0):

As you have said in your comment, it seems that the public key of euca-demo.private is associated with the cloud-user user in the VM. So you can SSH via this user only.